# copy specific column value to another column that matches specific string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Python lib pandas. For all the rows in a data frame in which a specific column matches a specific string, I want to copy that value from the column at the left to the current column.

For example, for all rows with the column City with the value 'not available', I want to copy the value from the column at the left, let's say Country, to the current column City.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['France','England','U.S.A','Spain'],
               'City': ['Paris','London','not available','not available']})

print(df)

    Country    City
0    France   Paris
1   England  London
2     U.S.A     not available
3     Spain     not available
```

Comment: Hi there, are you able to provide a [mcve] a few rows of your data and what you want the output to be. Your own attempt would also be appreciated to show others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve this. One is using the loc property:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['France','England','U.S.A','Spain'],
                   'City': ['Paris','London','N/A','N/A']})

print(df)

    Country    City
0    France   Paris
1   England  London
2     U.S.A     N/A
3     Spain     N/A
```

Then:

```
df.loc[df['City'] == 'N/A', 'City'] = df['Country']

    Country    City
0    France   Paris
1   England  London
2     U.S.A   U.S.A
3     Spain   Spain
```

For more complex recipes check the [Cookbook](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html)

Comment: Thanks ! That was a great and complete solution!